# Thin Lens as phase transformation

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, lenses

In Introduction to Fourier Optics,  J. Goodman, Chapter 5, the lens is analyzed as a phase transformation due to its variable thickness on the transverse plane xy.

[image]

Under paraxial approximation, the book finds the following lens phase transfer function:

$$ T(x,y) = e^{-j\frac{k}{2f}\cdot (x^2 + y^2)}$$

and then it states:

> This equation will serve as our basic representation of the effects of a thin lens on an
> incident disturbance. It neglects the finite extent of the lens, which we will account for
> later. We may interpret this expression as a quadratic approximation to a spherical wave. Our conclusion that a lens composed of spherical surfaces maps an incident plane
> wave into a spherical wave is very much dependent on the paraxial approximation.

Why is the previous expression a spherical wave in case of input plane wave? From my really basic EM studies, a spherical wave looks like

$$ E = \frac{E_0}{r} \cdot e^{-j\frac{k}\cdot r}$$

where $r = \sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$

Where is the amplitude attenuation term in the lens? Why isn't there the square root?

Answer (score 3):

Attenuation is neglected. $r=\sqrt{z^2+x^2+y^2}\approx z+\frac{x^2+y^2}{2z}$, $z$ being distance along lens axis (paraxial approximation), for the situation in question $z=F$. For the denominator $r$ is put $r\approx F$